# OP comments vs votes and accepts

Tags: discussion

An OP has commented that my answer was correct and resolved his problem, but he didn't vote for it, or accept it. Is there anything to be done, or just let it go?

Comment: Meta effect strikes (in terms of upvotes) again. Waiting to be able to remove the parenthesis.

Comment: @GrantGarrison: Pardon me, but the meaning of your comment escapes me completely... could you elaborate?

Comment: Meta effect is an effect where a question mentioned on meta receives a lot of attention.

Comment: Did this question receive a lot of attention? It didn't seem so to me, but perhaps this group is smaller than I imagine it to be.

Comment: *This* question is not relevant here. The question that is being referred to is what is relevant.

Comment: Ohh-kayyy... I think I'm going to crawl out of the rabbit hole now, but have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you should not pressure the OP to vote and/or accept your answer; despite the fact that most of us would obviously agree that voting and accepting is beneficial to the idea of Stackexchange - upvotes or acceptance signals an answer is helpful and thus worthwhile reading - and to the users participating (yeah, virtual internet points as an incentive to provide quality content).

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers says:

> What should I do when someone answers my question?
>   Decide if the answer is helpful, and then...
>
> - **Vote on it** (if you have earned the appropriate voting privilege). Vote up answers that are helpful and well-researched, and vote down answers that are not. Other users will also vote on answers to your question.
> - **Accept it.** As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Note that it says *should* not *must*. In this particular case it is however noteworthy that the OP cannot not yet upvote your answer due to the lacking reputation (in other words the answer itself lacks upvotes in the first place). He could still accept your answer though and I am usually fine with a comment indicating just that.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm gonna' let it go. If he's not bothered to read the rules of engagement, then I'll just not engage with him.

Comment: *"you should not pressure the OP to vote and/or accept your answer"* -> I disagree, if pressure includes politely asking someone who is obviously a new user and may not understand how things work.  While it would be nice to believe everyone takes time out to read the docs, I'm quite sure most people don't.

Comment: "pressure" is exactly the opposite of asking politely. That is the point IMHO (which maybe I did not make properly). That is why I said that pointing it out nicely is fine (... and that there is a technical reason that the OP could not have upvoted the answer), @goldilocks

Comment: Actually you said, somewhat ambiguously, "I am usually fine with a comment indicating just that". :P

Comment: @goldilocks ... and putting a comment to that end on the question itself ;) the OP however has not yet chosen to act on that either.

Comment: Beg your pardon, but the OP indicated that he has chosen not to act :) It just doesn't "feel right" to me to have to point this out. And that's why I've not selected either of the answers offered... so don't pressure me  :) LOL

Answer (score 4):

> you should not pressure the OP to vote and/or accept your answer

*- Ghanima*

I'm going to disagree with this, if we take "pressure" to include a polite response.  I think there is at least one scenario where it is okay: If this is the OP's first question, or if looking through his/her other questions from the profile link, you notice s/he has never accepted an answer.  This is a clue the OP may not understand this part of the system.

Of course, if that person had taken the [new user tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and/or read other Q&A's -- both of which I would hope someone would do before asking, but a surprising number of people clearly do not<sup>1</sup> -- they would likely have picked up on this.  The fact that so many of them do not is testimony to the single-mindedness of people who want help please with their problem *now*.

That's understandable, and if that person then thanks you in a comment but doesn't tick the check, it's probably because they don't get it.  In this case, I think there's nothing wrong with a polite:

> If you this answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it by ticking the big checkmark at the top on the left.

I do this occasionally (on my own and other people's answers), and I notice other people having done it, and most of the time the OP does exactly that.  Although it may seem aggressive, it is helpful if the OP really didn't understand (and might otherwise continue on asking questions and never accepting an answer).  If they already know, I think most reasonable people would take it for what it is: A tip to someone they think needs it.  No harm no foul!

---

1. You can tell if someone has taken the tour if they have the ["Informed"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed) badge. Only ~10% of our members actually have that, despite the fact that you are invited to do so when you sign up (that's not adjusted for people who came from other SE sites where they may have taken the tour). If they don't, and they don't have other SE memberships, that's a clue they did not take the tour.

   The majority of people who post questions as answers (go figure), and/or get their first question closed by me for whatever reason, fall into this category (which is why I politely ask them to "Please take the tour...").

Comment: "Of course, if that person had taken the new user tour" BUT the site makes it difficult to find the tour. I KNOW it is there, but still have difficulty finding it - This should be at the TOP, not buried at the bottom, which on my browser if way off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Milliways Actually there's a question mark (a fairly universal symbol...) in the top bar on the right; if you click on that the first item (on the main site -- here it's second) is the tour.  Also you are invited to take this when you sign up -- but I appreciate that when people have to go through  a tedious sign up processes in pursuit of a solution to their problems, they may have blinders on.  I won't claim I'm any different (i.e., I often don't meet standards "I would hope..." others might above).

Comment: I think it comes down to something about complexity and how much new information we are willing and able to meaningfully absorb at once.   People still ask how to ask how to use the editor despite the fact there's a question mark on the right there too.  Perhaps the best thing to do with interfaces who's complexity reflects something about a mean of *long term* users is to have a simplified one for new users.

Comment: Yep plain an simple Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange is hard on new Users!